# How to get the slug of the homepage when editing it in WP admin?

Tags: php

According to the [WP_Class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) reference, `$post->post_name` holds the value of the slug of the current page being viewed. If I'm currently viewing the WP admin edit screen for my homepage as set under Settings > Reading > Front page displays > A static page > Front page, what would be the value of `$post->post_name` if I do the following?

```
global $post;
echo $post->post_name;
```

I wasn't aware my homepage had a slug. Would the value be an empty string? Hoping someone can help clarify. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that reference to the $post object only applies on the front end.

Comment: I think it applies to the edit screen as well.

Comment: @vancoder on 2nd thoughts, I think you might be right

Comment: @vancoder on 3rd thoughts, I think it does actually apply to the edit screen as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post_name` would be the slug as it was set before the page became the front page. When the URL for the front page is output via the API, the `get_page_link` function checks if the ID matches the `page_on_front` option and returns the `home_url` in that case. This is why you should always use the API to output data and not directly access post object fields.